# Sympy function does not recognize assumptions about variables

Tags: function, sympy, interpretation

I have a piecewise function that differentiates between positive and negative arguments. When I feed it explicit numbers it goes well, but when I enter a symbol it does not evaluate the function, even though I defined the symbol as positive.

This is how my code looks:

```
lamb = sym.symbols("lamb")
y = sym.symbols("y", positive=True)

class mu(sym.Function):

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, x):
        if x.is_Number:
            if x < 0:
                return lamb*x
            else:
                return x


print(mu(y))
print(y>0)
print(mu(y).subs(y,4))
```

And this returns:

```
mu(y)
True
4
```

Where for the first `print` statement I'd like it to return just `y`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you check `if x.is_Number`? That will always be False for a symbol

Comment: I second @OscarBenjamin 's suggestions. Removing the `is_Number` check will make the code work as expected.

Comment: Thanks @OscarBenjamin, this solves my problem (and I don't have a good explanation for why I put this check there, I just copied it from some place else and edited it and didn't think of deleting this check). Anyway, this caused a different problem, which I was able to fix - now I couldn't run `mu(y)` if `y`'s sign is not known (I would like to get in return `mu(y)` in such a case). So what I did is instead of `if x.is_Number:` I put `if (x>0).is_Boolean:`, and this seems to do the job. I'm new to this community, should I now edit the question and add the result?

Comment: If you want to ask about that then I suggest asking a new question. In general though what you are creating here is already handled in sympy by the Piecewise function.